# saving a value with multiple keys on hyperledger fabric using go chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to save a value with multiple keys on hyperledger fabric blockchain using go chaincode.

For example i have an asset that i want to query using its `id` and `name`.
One approach is that i can do a `PutState(..)` twice, once with its `id` and then with `name` keys.

```
err := stub.PutState('256', []byte("My Value"))
err = stub.PutState('nissan26',[]byte("My Value"))
```

But the problem is when i make changes using one key it does not reflects in other.

Is it possible to approach something like this in go chaincode?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to query for an asset based on either the `id` or the `name`.  While it's possible to come up with a scheme to do this using the default state store (which is just an embedded key/value store), the preferred method would be to use [CouchDB](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/couchdb_as_state_database.html#) as your state store.  When using CouchDB, you can model your assets using JSON and then use the rich query APIs in chaincode to query based on any of the fields.